# Logstash: NoMethodError: method `>=’ for nil:NilClass Logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

Here is my configuration file:

I got the following error :

Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash. 
Exception in pipelineworker, the pipeline stopped processing new events, please check your filter configuration and restart Logstash. 
NoMethodError: undefined method `>=' for nil:NilClass

Do you how to solve this problem please ?!!

Thank you for your attention and your help.

Joe

Comment: configuration file:filter {
if [log][Frequency] != [] {
    if [log][Frequency] >= 866.0 {
        mutate {
            add_field => ["[log][subband]", "7"] 
        }
   }
}
}

Comment: Can you try `if [log][Frequency] != ""` ?

Comment: I tried but I still get the same error

Comment: When you get that error, can you verify the value of the field `[log][Frequency]` in the event? What is it?

Comment: How i am supposed to do it ? when i put '==' or '!=' it works with no error.

Comment: Before that can you simply try `if [log][Frequency] {` ?

Comment: ok it works ! thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply change the if condition in your filter like this:

```
filter { 
   if [log][Frequency] { 
      if [log][Frequency] >= 866.0 { 
         mutate { 
            add_field => ["[log][subband]", "7"] 
         }
      }
   }
}
```